# How to enable remote access to framework 4.0 in windows 2012 server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, remote-access, windows-server-2012

Hi I have an application which can edit the web.config file of an application hosted in remote server with right credentials. But for that first i need to enable remote access to the asp.net framework in the remote server.
aspnet_regiis -config+  is the key for that.
I have successfully enabled it in windows 2003 server and the application is working fine.
But when it comes to 2012 server I am not able to enable the remote access.It is showing the following error in cmd.

> "Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.18408 Administration
>   utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. This option
>   is not supported on this version of the operating system."

Any idea how can i enable remote access in Windows 2012 server?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45`

Comment: is this for registering asp.net 4 or enabling remote access? also where i need to apply this. sorry I am not expert in handling server.

Comment: This is on the command line instead of aspnet_regiis to avoid the error you got.  You haven't exactly been clear on what you did to enable remote access and what errors you got.

Answer (score 0):

[Taken from here.](http://windowsserver2012.itpro.co.uk/how-guides/60/configuring-remote-capabilities-windows-server-2012/page/0/1)

**Install Remote Access server role:**
The Remote Access server role in Windows Server 2012 has changed. It combines DirectAccess, Routing and Remote Access into a single unified server role. This is what makes it easier to install and configure. The PowerShell Cmdlet for installing the Remote Access server role is:

```
Install-WindowsFeatures RemoteAccess -IncludeManagementTools
```

**The steps to do this through the GUI interface are:** Open Server manager and select Add Roles and Features. This starts the installation wizard. Click through the wizard until the list of available Server Roles is displayed (fig 2). From this list, select Remote Access and this will open up a list of features that are available for Remote Access. Click Add Features to install the default set of features and then keep clicking next to move through the wizard.

On the Role Service page, make sure the DirectAccess and VPN (RAS) option is checked.

Continue through the wizard and select install. Once the Remote Access role has been added you can close the wizard. Like many other roles in Windows Server 2012, there is no need to restart the server when adding the Remote Access role although some of the other features it installs may require a reboot.

Once the Remote Access role is installed, it will add a Remote Access menu option in the Server Manager menu. This opens Remote Access and tells you that it has not been activated. Hover over the highlighted server and right click to bring up a menu. From this menu select Remote Access Management. This will start the Remote Access Setup. Click on Run the Getting Started Wizard to begin configuration.